# How to edit WSDL location in VUGen-Manage Services Window?

Tags: web-service, loadrunner

Hi I am using Web services Scripting using Loadrunner - Virtual User Generator and recorded successfully but as per team decision, IP address and port number is changed in WSDL URL, now I want to edit IP address and Port number for old WSDL IP address and Port number. I am able to change IP Address and Port number in Manage Services Window using Override Address but not able to Change WSDL Location (which is showing old IP address and port number).P lease find below screen shot for more details.

[image]

Because of this in **Test Results** window showing as below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Import a new service, not use the "Override address"  I'd go ahead and remove your current service definition, and then import a new one, pointing to the new WSDL.

The purpose of "Override address" would be if you already have an existing WSDL out there, but want to point to a test infrastructure instead of the current infrastructure.  You could use the same WSDL, but then direct traffic to a different server . . .